# Querying on enum's method in Hiberate Criteria API

Tags: hibernate, spring, enums

I have an `@Entity` which has an `@Enumerated` field mapped to it:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Device implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private DeviceType typeOfDevice;

    [....]

}
```

`DeviceType` is a typical java 5 enum:

```
public enum DeviceType {
  MOBILE(true), EMAIL(false);
  private final boolean fubar;

  private DeviceType(boolean fubar) {
    this.fubar= fubar;
  }

  public boolean isFubar() {
    return fubar;
  }
}
```

How can i query for `Device` entities which have `typeOfDevice.isFubar() == true`?

```
return factory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Device.class).
       add(Restrictions.eq("typeOfDevice.isFubar", true)).list();
```

isn't doing the job as well as :

```
return factory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Device.class).
       createCriteria("typeOfDevice").add(Restrictions.eq("fubar", true)).list();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like a solution to your problem might be along the lines of:

```
Criteria criteria = factory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Device.class);
Disjunction or = Restrictions.disjunction();

for (DeviceType type : DeviceType.values()) {
    if (type.isFubar()) {
        or.add(Restrictions.eq("typeOfDevice", type));
    }
}

criteria.add(or);

return criteria;
```

Instead of doing `where typeOfDevice.fubar = true`, we're approaching it more along the lines of `where (typeOfDevice = Mobile OR typeOfDevice = OtherFubar OR typeOfDevice = OtherOtherFubar)`. I realize this isn't the one-liner you were originally shooting for, but I think it answers the question as asked.

Answer (score 5):

You have anotated it as

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
```

this will store the name of the enum. Your db column will have either "MOBILE" or "EMAIL" but not 'true' or 'false'. you can change your query to

```
 return factory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Device.class).
   add(Restrictions.eq("typeOfDevice", DeviceType.MOBILE)).list();
```

Its more reable isn't?

Comment: It is. It really is. Unfortunately it's not what I was looking for. I don't want to query on the typeOfDevice; I want to query on isFubar() ...

Comment: you can't do that, the fubar information is not store in db and hibernate can not understand.

Comment: That is the problem: hibernate can not map back to the enum inside the criteria. And I thought maybe there is a way to enable that.