# Hibernate Like Criteria on Enum field

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, hibernate-mapping

Given a Hibernate Entity `Foo`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
class Foo {
    //ID Field

    @Column(name = "bar", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Bar bar;

    //Getters, Setters
}
```

And an Enum `Bar`

```
enum Bar {
    CAT,
    CRADLE,
    SILVER,
    SPOON;
}
```

I would like to run a query checking if Foo.bar's value contains some String `matchString` = "ADL".

Currently, my DetachedCriteria object is constructed as:

```
DetachedCriteria.forClass(Foo.class)
    .add(Restrictions.like("bar", matchString, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));`
```

but causes a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum` when invoked.

Comment: If you use an `enum` then it's because you have a defined set of values. Use an `enum` as an `enum` not as a coerced `String`. Use `in` and the values you need.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, the use case is for a user to live filter a list of `Foo` such that as the user types the items are filtered.

Comment: As far as UI goes, an `enum` should be a dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A query like this would only be possible if the enum is persisted using the String value rather than the ordinal - but even then I would not expect the criteria API to necessarily support a like for enums.

Instead of trying to do the like at the database level you can find all the enums where the name contains "bar" (in Java code) and then query for all the matches where "bar" is in that set. This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/18899529/4248600.

```
Disjunction or = Restrictions.disjunction();
for (BarEnum bar : BarEnum.values()) {
    if (bar.name().contains(matchStr)) {
        or.add(Restrictions.eq("bar", bar));
    }
}
criteria.add(or);
```